# Rendering FontAwsome Icon inside a CSS2DObject with VueJS

Tags: vue.js, three.js, vue-component, font-awesome

I want to render a [FontAwsome User Icon](https://fontawesome.com/icons/user?s=solid&f=classic) as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74522180) inside a VueJS component, I have tried to replicate the same example as you can see in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cssobject-arrow-x88915?file=/src/views/ThreeScene.vue), and I have tried the two approaches as the latter mentioned in [the documentation](https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/use-with/vue), and applied the [corresponding settings](https://codesandbox.io/s/cssobject-arrow-x88915?file=/src/main.js):

1. `el.innerHTML = "Hi <i class='fa-solid fa-user'</i>";`
2. `el.innerHTML = "Hi <font-awesome-icon icon='fa-solid fa-user' />";`

but the FontAwsome Icon was not rendered inside a VueJs component, can you please tell me How can I solve that please? thanks in advance.

Comment: I recommend a more universal solution like that one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72055404/8816585 Efficient and simple.

Comment: @kissu thanks for your kind suggestion, I will give it a try, and report back to you.

Comment: @kissu thanks to your suggestion I found a simple solution by using SVG directly `el.innerHTML = 'Erreur <svg viewBox="0 0 384 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M224 402.7V32c0-17.7-14.3-32-32-32s-32 14.3-32 32v370.7l-73.4-73.3c-12.5-12.5-32.8-12.5-45.3 0s-12.5 32.8 0 45.3l128 128c12.5 12.5 32.8 12.5 45.3 0l128-128c12.5-12.5 12.5-32.8 0-45.3s-32.8-12.5-45.3 0L224 402.7z"></path></svg>';` the other solution was  complex for me to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP ended up using the following

```js
el.innerHTML = 'Erreur <svg viewBox="0 0 384 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M224 402.7V32c0-17.7-14.3-32-32-32s-32 14.3-32 32v370.7l-73.4-73.3c-12.5-12.5-32.8-12.5-45.3 0s-12.5 32.8 0 45.3l128 128c12.5 12.5 32.8 12.5 45.3 0l128-128c12.5-12.5 12.5-32.8 0-45.3s-32.8-12.5-45.3 0L224 402.7z"></path></svg>';
```